# Ignore parse `CDATA` by `dataSet.ReadXml` in C#

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I have a xml like this:

```
<dictionary>
    <string key="Test">
        <value><![CDATA[<b>Test Data</b>]]></value>
    </string>       
</dictionary>
```

I load this xml in DataSet. After load with `dataSet.ReadXml` remove `CDATA` from value. I need `CDATA` as value in the DataSet. I need this data:

```
--------------------------------------------
|  Key    |         Value                  |
--------------------------------------------
|  Test   | <![CDATA[<b>Test Data</b>]]>   |
--------------------------------------------
```

How I can ignore parse `CDATA` when read xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can obtain what you want:

```
using (StringReader stream = new StringReader("<dictionary> <string key=\"Test\"> <value><![CDATA[<b>Test Data</b>]]></value> </string> </dictionary>"))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
    XElement element = doc.Descendants("value").First();
    string value = element.LastNode.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> <![CDATA[<b>Test Data</b>]]>
> ```